# Type error: ',' expected when running yarn build

Tags: error-handling, yarnpkg, vercel

I'm working with this template from github for Nextjs/BigCommerce and I'm trying to integrate Webflow into it by following this article https://dev.to/kennedyrose/integrating-webflow-and-next-js-39kk.

The article requires me to add a few packages, such as cheerios, axios, html-react-parser (all added with yarn add)

Yarn dev works fine, but when I run yarn build, I receive the following error

```
"Type error: ',' expected."
```

What is the issue here?
Thanks!

PS: I've updated typescript to the latest version

Edit: here is the error log

```
next-commerce:build: Failed to compile.
next-commerce:build:
next-commerce:build: ../node_modules/cheerio-select/lib/index.d.ts:1:15
next-commerce:build: Type error: ',' expected.
next-commerce:build:
next-commerce:build: > 1 | import { type Options as CSSSelectOptions } from "css-select";
next-commerce:build:     |               ^
next-commerce:build:   2 | import type { Element, AnyNode, Document } from "domhandler";
next-commerce:build:   3 | export { filters, pseudos, aliases } from "css-select";
next-commerce:build:   4 | export interface Options extends CSSSelectOptions<AnyNode, Element> {
next-commerce:build:
next-commerce:build: > Build error occurred
next-commerce:build: Error: Call retries were exceeded
next-commerce:build:     at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (C:\Users\User\Documents\My-Bigcommerce\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\jest-worker\index.js:1:11661)
next-commerce:build:     at ChildProcessWorker._onExit (C:\Users\User\Documents\My-Bigcommerce\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\jest-worker\index.js:1:12599)
next-commerce:build:     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
next-commerce:build:     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12) {
next-commerce:build:   type: 'WorkerError'
next-commerce:build: }
next-commerce:build: error Command failed with exit code 1.
next-commerce:build: info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
next-commerce:build: ERROR: command finished with error: command (site) yarn run build exited (1)
command (site) yarn run build exited (1)

 Tasks:    11 successful, 12 total
Cached:    11 cached, 12 total
  Time:    5.672s

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code and error as text and not as an image.

Comment: What typescript version do you use?

Comment: Thanks! Updated the post. 
And I've updated to the latest version : 4.7.4

Comment: Is there a solution to this?

Comment: I got the same error. Were you able to resolve this issue please?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and updating Typescript to its latest version fixed the problem. I installed typescript@4.9.5.

You can install the latest version with the next command:

```
yarn add typescript@latest
// or 
npm install typescript@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this and the issue for me was I was using an outdated version of cheerio. Fixed it by running

```
yarn add cheerio@latest
```

Then yarn build ran fine.